# Will ffmpeg encode faster if I have a Graphics Card?

Tags: graphics-card, ffmpeg

Naive question perhaps ; I hae a bunch of videos on my phone in 3gp format.
My intent is to save them to disc after converting them to AVI/FLV

The amount of time required for such encoding is not known to me; but I wonder ... will ffmpeg encode faster if my computer has a graphics card with 512MB to 1GB on it?

Comment: GPU offloading is done if the video codec supports it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. Drivers, the encoder you use, the video card you choose, all these will affect whether and how much the video card will be involved in the encoding.

With cell-phone video, the quality of the stream is likely low enough that unless there is a particular effect you need, it will not be economically feasible to purchase a new video just for this purpose.

Unless you're working on a professional project, just use Handbrake and the hardware you currently have. Install the latest drivers for your mainboard (chipset), video card and sound card, to make sure they can all function in any way the software will utilize them, and just use what you've got.